# How to resolve merge conflict while rebasing?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-merge-conflict

```
interactive rebase in progress; onto 2e0a7b5
Last commands done (6 commands done):
   f 6d90337 show_user POD reworked
   f 3bafc68 Minor Updates in User.pm POD
  (see more in file .git/rebase-merge/done)
Next command to do (1 remaining command):
   f 6c3632d Moved /wiki/ into /lib/wiki/
  (use "git rebase --edit-todo" to view and edit)
You are currently rebasing branch 'wiki' on '2e0a7b5'.
  (fix conflicts and then run "git rebase --continue")
  (use "git rebase --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git rebase --abort" to check out the original branch)

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)

1   added by them:   ../lib/wiki/user_registration.pod
2   added by us:     Registration.pod
3   both deleted:    user_registration.pod

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I use next commands to resolve conflict:

```
git add Registration.pod
git add user_registration.pod
git rm ../lib/wiki/user_registration.pod
```

`git status` after this:

```
interactive rebase in progress; onto 2e0a7b5
Last commands done (6 commands done):
   f 6d90337 show_user POD reworked
   f 3bafc68 Minor Updates in User.pm POD
  (see more in file .git/rebase-merge/done)
Next command to do (1 remaining command):
   f 6c3632d Moved /wiki/ into /lib/wiki/
  (use "git rebase --edit-todo" to view and edit)
You are currently rebasing branch 'wiki' on '2e0a7b5'.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

But I can not continue rebasing `git rebase --continue`

```
error: could not apply 6c3632d... Moved /wiki/ into /lib/wiki/

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".

fatal: Unable to create '/home/kes/work/projects/artcoin.io/artcoin/.git/MERGE_RR.lock': File exists.

If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
process is running and remove the file manually to continue.

Could not apply 6c3632d9d00bdc97ba3879cd3a10a2517891b284... Moved /wiki/ into /lib/wiki/
fatal: Unable to create '/home/kes/work/projects/artcoin.io/artcoin/.git/MERGE_RR.lock': File exists.

If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
process is running and remove the file manually to continue.
```

How to resolve such conflicts and continue rebasing?

Comment: Tried using `git mergetool`?

Comment: @LuísFelipeNogoseke: `$ git mergetool`
`Segmentation fault`
`No files need merging`

Comment: Looking at :  `1   added by them:   ../lib/wiki/user_registration.pod` and `3  both deleted:    user_registration.pod`  Shouldn't you have done  `git add ../lib/wiki/user_registration.pod` and `git rm user_registration.pod`?

Answer (score 1):

I resolve it by explicitly doing as last command after those I have done:

```
git mv ../wiki/Registration.pod wiki/Registration.pod
```

All commands:

```
git add Registration.pod
git add user_registration.pod
git rm ../lib/wiki/user_registration.pod
git mv ../wiki/Registration.pod wiki/Registration.pod
```

After removing this file (because of SegFault):

```
rm /home/kes/work/projects/artcoin.io/artcoin/.git/MERGE_RR.lock
```

I continue rebasing:

```
git rebase --continue
```

**UPD**

Another thing I have noticed that after `git commit` despite on error message:

```
fatal: Unable to create '/home/kes/work/projects/artcoin.io/artcoin/.git/MERGE_RR.lock': File exists.

If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
process is running and remove the file manually to continue.
```

Commit is commited